# Change File Upload Path

Tags: strapi

How do I change the default path for the file upload in Strapi? I want to store the uploaded files to a network filer instead of the location where strapi is installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that you can install in order to upload to 3th party cloud storage platform

These are the official ones:

[strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3)

[strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary)

[strapi-provider-upload-rackspace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-rackspace)

You can check out this article for the detailed implementation https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/upload.html#install-providers